# How can I see a web page “birthday” and older versions of it?

Tags: web

Sometimes I want to see when was an article was published and it's not written on the web page.

Are there websites that show this information for free?

Secondly, Are there websites that show history of a URL/website?

Comment: This site is for software recommendations, not how to do things. To be a fit for this site, you question would have to be in the format *I'm looking for a program app that does x.*

Comment: Recommendations for web-apps are also within scope, rewording this to be a web-app recommendation is on the fringe... not out of the question, but on the fringe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't update constantly, but the Wayback Machine at http://web.archive.org scans everything it can, saving snapshots, etc. of sites as they exist at any given moment. Going back years.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't cover the 2 sites I'm currently examining. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

"LastModified Date" is a Firefox extension that displays last modification date / time of web pages in the url bar. I have had mixed results - it doesn't seem to work on every site.

[image: Screenshot]

[LastModified Date extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lastmodified-date/?src=api)

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky, you can use the Document.lastModified Javascript function which should be available in most browsers. If the page is dynamically generated (IE: Generated just for your browsing) then it will show the the time/date when you loaded the page, which is pretty useless to you.

However, if it is a static HTML page, it will show the last modified date for that file.

Navigate to the webpage in your browser, then in your address bar type:

```
javascript:alert(document.lastModified)
```

This should only be used as a last resort, as it is possible that the website generated this data at a certain time that does not correspond to when it was written.